# wget failing for no obvious reason

Tags: .htaccess, cron, wget

I have a problem using wget to create a cron job.
When I use this command:

```
wget -U http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/plugin_name/export.php
```

I get this message:

```
--2013-11-21 11:29:01--  http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/plugin_name/export.php
Resolving example.com... 255.255.255.255
Connecting to example.com|255.255.255.255|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2013-11-21 11:29:01 ERROR 403: Forbidden.#
```

So I researched this and tried using the browser spoofing trick like so:

```
wget -U 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070802 SeaMonkey/1.1.4' http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/plugin_name/export.php
```

But this returns:

```
--2013-11-21 11:36:02--  http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/plugin_name/export.php
Resolving example.com... 255.255.255.255
Connecting to example.com|255.255.255.255|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2013-11-21 11:36:03 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

I can't find any reason for this to occur and I'm a bit stumped.
I am not running any kind of agent blocking

Answer (score 0):

Well there is an obvious answer. The request returns '403 Forbidden' what either indicates missing/insufficient authentication from the client or missing/insufficient access privileges for the user on server side.

Can you run the request from a normal browser w/o wget?